# Why is this map injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

On the [page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9_alg%C3%A9brique_affine) we find the following: 
$ \phi : Z ( P_1 , \dots , P_r ) \to \mathrm {Spm} (K[ X_1 , \dots , k_n ] / \sqrt{ ( P_1 , \dots , P_r )}) $ defined by $ \phi ( ( a_1 , \dots , a_n ) = \pi ( ( X_1 - a_1 , \dots , X_n - a_n ) ) $ is injective, and when $ K $ is algebraically closed, $ \phi $ is bijective. Can you explain me why?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The injectivity is due to the fact, that maximal ideals in $K[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]/\sqrt{(P_1, \dotsc, P_r)}$ correspond via $\pi$ to maximal ideals in $K[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$ that contain $(P_1, \dotsc, P_r)$.

The ideals $(X_1-a_1, \dotsc, X_n-a_n)$ contain $(P_1, \dotsc, P_r)$ if and only if $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) \in Z(P_1, \dotsc, P_r)$. Hence all the ideals $\pi((X_1-a_1, \dotsc, X_n-a_n))$ with $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) \in Z(P_1, \dotsc, P_r)$ are distinct, since they are in bijection with the ideals $(X_1-a_1, \dotsc, X_n-a_n)$ and these are known to be distinct.

The surjectivity in the algebraically closed case is due to the Nullstellensatz, which states that any maximal ideal is of that form.